# Is there a way to permanently delete/remove an app from the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have several applications in the Windows store and I've stopped supporting some of them.
I don't want to just unpublish them or make them unavailable, but completely get rid of them.

How can I permanently remove them so that their names can be reused again by others.

Thanks,
robcsi

Answer (score 2):

Currently, for the app you have never submitted to the Store, you could click **Delete this app** in the upper right corner of the **App overview page**, which also releases the reserved name so that you and someone else can use it. However, you’re not able to delete an app from your dashboard once it’s been published. You can **make it unavailable** or select **Hide this app and stop selling** in the **Distribution and visibility** section.

If you just want to reuse the name of them, you don’t need to permanently remove them. You could go to the **Manage app names** page in the **App management** section for any of your apps in the Windows Dev Center Dashboard. You can click **Delete** to remove the name you want, which means this name will immediately be available for someone else to reserve and use.

But please note that your app needs to have at least one reserved name. So you might have to reserve a new name for them before deleting the old one.

More details, please see [Manage app names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names).

Comment: The apps are submitted to store, but made unavailable, so I'm unable to have a "Delete this app" button. Also the "Delete" button is not available in the App management section, so I wrote to the store team about it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: “Delete this app” button is only available for the app you have never submitted to the store. In you case, the only way is to renew a new name for your old app and delete the name you want to reuse.

Comment: @robcsi dev center support will be able to rename the app (to release original name) but they won't delete the app from your list of apps. I had the same issue few weeks ago.

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT Hi Mattew, what if I want to have my application published for the first time on Win Store to be only available for beta testers, should I go for "Hide this app and stop selling" + Generating promotion codes for the beta testers? or stop selling option will disable the promotion codes? Thank you